# Sorting multidimensional array in java without using collections

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
String Name[][]={
    {"prakash","kumar"},
    {"raj","kappor"},
    {"vinod","bhart"},
    {"yraj","tkappor"},                         
    {"avinod","fbhart"}
};
```

Can we sort this string array surname first, then firstname without using collections ?

Comment: The answer is `Yes`. If you give more details on what you tried, you could get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the arrays in place using [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class.
In this case it would look something like this:

```
    Arrays.sort(Name, new Comparator<String[]>(){
        int LASTNAME=0, FIRSTNAME=1;

        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            int c = o1[LASTNAME].compareTo(o2[LASTNAME]);
            if (c != 0) return c;
            return o1[FIRSTNAME].compareTo(o2[FIRSTNAME]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't want to use collections.I tried all possible ways, but without using Collections i am not getting how to solve this

Comment: There is no collections involved in my answer. What is wrong with collections? What problems do you have with my answer? Does the code compile? Are the reaults wrong?

Comment: Dear Panu, i tried your code but its not working properly. its like

Comment: If a[0][1] compare with a[1][1] for surname returns equal, then it checks with firstnames. i appreciate your answer and help. but if you can write the complete program, it will help me a lot. thankyou

Comment: What do you mean? This code will first order names by lastname and if lastnames are equal then order is determined by firstnames. Isn't that what you requested?

Comment: Full source code can be seen here https://gist.github.com/pnuz3n/85761528fdef66d10609

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<T> Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator))) to sort generic arrays and specify a custom comparator that in your case compares two `String[]` by looking first at the surname and then at the first name (See [Panu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695126/sorting-multidimensional-array-in-java-without-using-collections/24695352#24695352) for a possible implementation).

If you don't want to use `Arrays` either, you will have to implement a sorting algorithm yourself. You can find a good overview of sorting algorithms [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/20sorting/). In order to use your custom comparison you will have to adapt the comparison methods.

Comment: I tried all possible ways, but without using Collections i am not getting how to solve this

Comment: @ChiranjibPatra You tried using `Arrays.sort`? What part is it you don't understand? You can always edit the question and add code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @ChiranjibPatra Hi - have you considered accepting an answer?

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks a lot for your answers. I couldn't concentrate in this topic due to some personal problems. I apologize for that and I will be back soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.sort(Name, ComparatorFactory.compareOn(ON.FIRSTNAME));

enum ON {
    FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, FULLNAME }

class ComparatorFactroy {
    static Comparator compareOn(ON on){
        switch (on) {
            case FIRSTNAME :
                return new Comparator<String[]>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(String[] tar) { ... }
                };
            case LASTNAME :
                return.....
            default:
                return ...
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final String[][] data = new String[][] {
            new String[] { "prakash","kumar" },
            new String[] { "raj","kappor" },
            new String[] { "vinod","bhart" },
            new String[] { "yraj","tkappor" },
            new String[] { "avinod","fbhart" }};

    Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
            final String time1 = entry1[0];
            final String time2 = entry2[0];
            return time1.compareTo(time2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use java's inbuilt sorting mechanism then you can implement one yourself something like this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<Name.length;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<Name.length;j++) {
            if(Name[i][1].compareTo(Name[j][1])>0) {
                String[] temp = Name[i];
                Name[i] = Name[j];
                Name[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.